# What is an English term for grouping bills and credit notes?

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests, hypernyms

I'm wondering if there is a generic term to talk about bills and credit notes, in other terms, the money I'll receive and the money I owe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might try: accounts, books, or ledger — all terms for the assembled and organized group (not just a pile of loose paper).

Comment: [AP vs AR](http://www.diffen.com/difference/Accounts_Payable_vs_Accounts_Receivable).

Comment: Don't see the point of the edit.

Comment: Then you could [rollback](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17038/what-is-a-rollback) the edit.

Comment: I ended up using accounting records

Answer (score 1):

You might consider [debits and credits](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debits_and_credits)

Comment: thanks but any single word to sum up both concepts?

Comment: I'd say accounts as suggested by Polymath